# The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an App Service in Azure, connected to a SQL Server database in Azure. The App Service has multiple timer-triggered WebJobs that interact with the database.

I am getting the following exception every time the SQL request is executed, and none of the existing advice helped me:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase. The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=124; handshake=49; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=0; [Post-Login] complete=14011;

The App Service tier is S1 and it has Always On enabled. The SQL tier is "General Purpose - Serverless: Standard-series (Gen5), 1 vCore".

The error occurs every time, regardless of the data. Yesterday it occurred on the data size of 5 records. According to the App Insights, the SQL Server request took 14 seconds before receiving this error.

The error never occurs when I am running the application locally on my PC, using the same Azure DB. That way it processed tens of thousands of records effortlessly, so I don't think it's a database configuration issue.

My best guess is I have some kind of problem with connection lifetime management in my app, since it works locally when the WebJob is executed immediately, but crashes on Azure when half a day passes since startup. I use EF Core, I registered app context like this:

```
collection
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database"),
                sqlServerOptions =>
                {
                    sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(3600);
                    sqlServerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), null);
                }))
```

...and all the services that use DB context are registered as "scoped".

Could also be the SQL Server firewall issue, but it does have the "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" option enabled.

Comment: Not a permanent solution perhaps, but add `Trust Server Certificate=True;` as a connection string attribute (though I confess I don't know how the heck you do that in the discombobulation known as EF Core). I just hit this one yesterday, and it can hold you over until you can do proper CA/cert stuff.

Comment: Have you checked the authentication details in (all of) your connection strings? The error message suggests that you might have `Integrated Security` or `Trusted_Connection` enabled (i.e.: Windows/Active Directory authentication).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the SQL Server request took 14 seconds before receiving this error.

The default ConnectionTimeout is 15sec.  And a Serverless database that has been paused typically takes longer than that to unpause.

> If a serverless database is paused, then the first login will resume
> the database and return an error stating that the database is
> unavailable with error code 40613. Once the database is resumed, the
> login must be retried to establish connectivity. Database clients with
> connection retry logic should not need to be modified. For connection
> retry logic options that are built-in to the SqlClient driver, see
> configurable retry logic in SqlClient.

[Serverless Compute Tier - Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview?view=azuresql&tabs=general-purpose#connectivity)

Comment: I'll try adding Connect Timeout=60 to a connection string. Thanks!

Comment: Like the doc says, you may need to retry even with a longer connection timeout.